# PIC Assembly: ISR for Timer1

Tags: assembly, pic

To perform ISR on Timer0, we use 0x04 address, or in code

```
ORG 0x04
GOTO tmr0_ISR
```

Which address should I use if I'm using Timer1 or does ISR for it requires different approach? (using PIC16F877A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the PIC16F877A, all interrupts trigger the same ISR stored at `0x04`.

Therefore, you need something along the lines of:

```
ORG 0x04
GOTO ISR
```

Elsewhere:

```
ISR:
  BTFSC INTCON, TMR0IF
    GOTO tmr0_ISR
  BTFSC PIR1, TMR1IF
    GOTO tmr1_ISR
```

My syntax might not be correct, it's been a while since I've written PIC16 assembly.

Comment: In your first line following `ISR:`, TMR01F should be `TMR0IF`.

Comment: Good catch. That's what I get for going fast and without compiling.